# Scripting Vim with find -exec

Tags: vim, find, replace

I have a little Vim script which does a multi-line search and replace:

```
vim -c 's/^ *<hi a=\"26\">\nHello/<td height=\"26\">\r<\/table>\r<bla \/>' \
    -c 'w!' -c 'q' test.html
```

That works. However, when I put that in a find -exec to do this recursively in the directory:

```
find . -iname 'test.html' -exec \
    vim -c 's/^ *<hi a=\"26\">\nHello/<td height=\"26\">\r<\/table>\r<bla \/>' \
    -c 'w!' -c 'q' \
{} \;
```

test.html remains unchanged, and Vim gives me this error:

```
Pattern not found:
  ^ *<hi a=\"26\">\nHello
in ./test.html
```

This is really strange because that is the correct regex, and I can search for it manually in Vim with success.

Can you see any obvious errors with my find syntax?

Comment: When you run `find` with just a `-print` instead of `-exec`, does it list test.html correctly?

Comment: Yes it does list test.html when I just do -print. It's successfully opening the file with Vim when I do -exec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out! The search pattern needed a % character: `vim -c '%s/switch/to/'` is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

When I do stuff like this, I tend to do it within vim.

```
:vimgrep /^ *<hi a=\"26\">\nHello/ **/*
```

followed by the creation and execution of a recursive macro:

```
qbq
qa (actually you don't press enter after this)
:silent! !p4 edit %  " check out the file
:e  " refresh the r/w status
:%s/^ *<hi a=\"26\">\nHello/<td height=\"26\">\r<\/table>\r<bla \/>
:w  " no need to force write if it's r/w
:cnf
q
qb@a@bq
@b
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the braces in the exec phrase (assuming you didn't, maybe the forum posting ate the back slashes).  It should end \{\} \;

Comment: Thanks, I escaped the curly braces. My original problem persists, though :(